# How i change this curl POST request into a c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, curl, http-post

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request using C# and this is all I know:

I have a template that is just plain text. They recommend storing it in a separate file, which makes it easier to pass to the request. and here is an example, if the template is in a file called `expensify_template.txt` this should be the call:

```
curl -X POST 'https://integrations.expensify.com/Integration-Server/ExpensifyIntegrations' \
    -d 'requestJobDescription={....}' \
    --data-urlencode 'template@expensify_template.txt'
```

and I have to make a code to send that request through c# using Visual Studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Comment: i know how to send the HTTP request with post only till i get to the --data-urlencode, i have already send this part: curl -X POST 'https://integrations.expensify.com/Integration-Server/ExpensifyIntegrations' \
    -d 'requestJobDescription={....}' i'm having a trouble with this one:  \
    --data-urlencode 'template@expensify_template.txt'

Comment: The answer is in the linked post still - specifically Method A where it says `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);` where `values` would be the result of your reading the text file that contains your template.  I'll remove the possible duplicate comment, however, since that question isn't specifically related to what you're asking.

Comment: Thank You VERY MUCH that was really really helpfull!!

Comment: You're welcome :) I'll post that in an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post) - specifically Method A where it says `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);` where values would be the result of your reading the text file that contains your template.